# How can I prompt for variables when launching Azure DevOps pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I'm trying to get Azure DevOps pipelines to prompt for a version number when manually launching a pipeline (defined using the new YAML syntax).

Even when I define variables in the template, the launch screen says "This pipeline has no defined variables".  How can I define variables so that they show up in the pipeline launch?

Current YAML definition contains:

```
variables:
  - name: versionName
    value: ''
```

These are not shown when launching the pipeline:

[image: Running the pipeline]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While [Shayki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67603893) is correct for defining variables, what I was really looking for is [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters).

With the following YAML definition:

```
parameters:
  - name: myParameter
    displayName: Description of myParameter
    default: defaultMyParameter
    type: string
```

it prompts for the parameter value when launching the pipeline:

[image: Pipeline prompting for myParameter]

The parameter must be referenced in the template using `${{ parameters.myParameter }}`, the other variable syntaxes don't work.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#allow-at-queue-time):

> If a `variable` appears in the variables block of a YAML file, its
> value is fixed and can't be overridden at queue time. Best practice is
> to define your variables in a YAML file but there are times when this
> doesn't make sense. For example, you may want to define a secret
> variable and not have the variable exposed in your YAML. Or, you may
> need to manually set a variable value during the pipeline run.
>
> You have two options for defining queue-time values. You can define a
> variable in the UI and select the option to **Let users override this
> value when running this pipeline** or you can use [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops)
> instead. If your variable is not a secret, the best practice is to use
> runtime parameters.
>
> To set a variable at queue time, add a new variable within your
> pipeline and select the override option.

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]
>
> To allow a variable to be set at queue time, make sure the variable
> doesn't also appear in the `variables` block of a pipeline or job. If
> you define a variable in both the variables block of a YAML and in the
> UI, the value in the YAML will have priority.